# Find number of new followers per day on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Ok I looked around and couldn't find the answer to this. So the twitter API doesn't make available the date/time a follower became a follower. If I wanted to figure out the number of new followers per day I would some how have to get the previous days and compare the two. Any idea how to do that effectively (like save snap shot every day and save to db or save a snap shot filter everyday save results).

Answer (score 1):

I'd save a snapshot in the DB for comparison.  If you store the name of each follower, you could also find out who quits you each day as well as who your new followers are.